# Is it ok to copy and paste and overwrite from google inspector tool

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am currently working on a new woocommerce checkout page, and i have run in some trouble or sort of. I found the best way to rip from woocommerce was to look through the Code with inspector and simply copy and past it into my checkout file such as /woocommerce/checkout/checkout.php.

Is there any problem with that?

In the following code i could figur out to find the hooks and etc from woocommerce' payment, so i just ripped it via the inspector tool:::

```
<ul class="wc_payment_methods payment_methods methods">
    <li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_maria">
        <input id="payment_method_maria" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="maria" checked="checked" data-order_button_text="">

        <label for="payment_method_maria">
            Pay with credit card <img src="https://cdn.mariapayment.com/logo/checkout/combo/horiz/MARIA_checkout_kombo_horizontal_04.png" alt="MARIA - Payments made easy" style="max-width:145px">   </label>
        <div class="payment_box payment_method_maria">
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wc_payment_method payment_method_maria_mobilepay">
        <input id="payment_method_maria_mobilepay" type="radio" class="input-radio" name="payment_method" value="maria_mobilepay" data-order_button_text="">

        <label for="payment_method_maria_mobilepay">
            MARIA MobilePay <img src="https://cdn.mariapayment.com/logo/checkout/single/horiz/MARIA_checkout_single_10.png" alt="MARIA - Payments made easy" style="max-width:98px">   </label>
        <div class="payment_box payment_method_maria_mobilepay" style="display:none;">
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

That it is ok to do so.

Answer (score 1):

This code is probably automatically generated, so you aren't really ripping from the source. If it does what you want, there's no real issue, though.

Answer (score 1):

As Marcel Roed already mentioned, this code is written in TypeScript and generated to HTML. You can copy it and use it like you want. To use it within WooCommerce, you need to modify the snippet anyway (add PHP and all the stuff you need).

But there is one thing I would be carful - the copyright. If this is a related to something you also do, it could be a problem (Just to remind).